# Php associative array value insertion, wrong key displaying

Tags: php, arrays, associative

Heres my problem. I have an associative array and would like the keys to match the item id of the item object passed into the function. If the item id key doesn't already exist in the array, I would like to add to the cart array the item id as a key along with a new array `["Item"=>$item,"Quantity=>1]` as the keys value.

If the key already exists I would just like to update the quantity stored in the array that would be retrieved by  indexing the cart array with the item id.

The following is the code I have that I thought would produce those results (located in Cart.class.php):

```
  private $cart_items = array();

  public function add_to_cart($item, $quantity = 1){
    if(!isset($item) || !isset($item->ItemID)){
        throw new Exception("Error adding item to cart");
    }
    if(!array_key_exists($item->ItemID,$this->cart_items)){
        $this->cart_items[$item->ItemID] = array("Item"=>$item,"Quantity"=>$quantity);
    }else{
        $this->cart_items[$item->ItemID]["Quantity"] += $quantity;
    }
    $this->number_of_cart_items+=$quantity;
}
```

However, when using `var_dump($this->cart_items)` the following is output:

```
    array(2){
   [
      0
   ]   => NULL   [
      1
   ]   => array(2)   {
      [
         "Item"
      ]      => object(stdClass)#2 (8)      {
         [
            "ItemID"
         ]         => int(11)         [
            "ItemName"
         ]         => string(18) "Kids check T-Shirt"         [
            "ShortDescription"
         ]         => string(20) "A kids check T-Shirt"         [
            "LongDescription"
         ]         => string(51) " A kids check T-shirt perfect for formal occasions!"         [
            "ItemPrice"
         ]         => float(33.59)         [
            "ImagePath"
         ]         => string(51) "kozzi-26129586-1591x2387.jpg"         [
            "QuantityAvailable"
         ]         => int(100)         [
            "ItemSupplier_SupplierID"
         ]         => int(1)
      }      [
         "Quantity"
      ]      => int(1)
   }
}
```

My problem is that `$item->ItemID` is not being used as a key for the associative array (you can see the keys are [0] [1], with the first one being null, even though I am using `$this->cart_items[$item->ItemID] = array()`.
My question is what am I doing wrong and why aren't the ids being used as the keys in the array?

Thanks

Comment: Do a var_dump($item) from inside the add_to_cart function

Comment: Yes, but I would like that ItemID to also be the index for the cart_items associative array.

Comment: I mean var_dump on $item and post the result here

Comment: I've tested this code and it works fine in v7. I agree with @Terminus, the item must not be what you are expecting...

Comment: could it be your item's ID is 1?

Comment: @JonathanChow from his posted var_dump, it's 11. But something strange is definitely going on in this guy's neighborhood, so idk

Comment: Yeah, the same item is stored as an std object in the array and you can see the id is 11. Which is why I'm not sure why a var_dump of item would show anything different, but none the less ill post one in a sec.

Comment: Are you calling the `var_dump()` outside of`add_to_cart()`? Are you passing the object by reference? If not, that's the problem, IMHO.

Comment: Did you fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Code works fine for me.

```
class Cart{

    private $cart_items = array();
    private $number_of_cart_items;

    public function add_to_cart($item, $quantity = 1){
        if(!isset($item) || !isset($item->ItemID)){
            throw new Exception("Error adding item to cart");
        }
        if(!array_key_exists($item->ItemID,$this->cart_items)){
            $this->cart_items[$item->ItemID] = array("Item"=>$item,"Quantity"=>$quantity);
        }else{
            $this->cart_items[$item->ItemID]["Quantity"] += $quantity;
        }
        $this->number_of_cart_items+=$quantity;
        return $this->cart_items;
    }
}


$itemArray = array(
    "ItemID" => 11,
    "ItemName" => "Kids check T-Shirt",
    "ShortDescription" => "A kids check T-Shirt",
    "LongDescription"=>"A kids check T-shirt perfect for formal occasions!",
    "ItemPrice" => 33.59,
    "ImagePath" => "kozzi-26129586-1591x2387.jpg",
    "QuantityAvailable" => 100,
    "ItemSupplier_SupplierID" => 1
);
$quantity = 1;
$item  = (object)$itemArray ;


$cart = new Cart();
$add_to_cart = $cart->add_to_cart($item,$quantity);


print_r($add_to_cart);    
var_dump($add_to_cart);
```

> Refer https://3v4l.org/N96Vc

Comment: The parameter passed to the `add_to_cart()` function is **not an array**; as the OP said, it's an *"item object passed"*. Read the description carfully!

Comment: Am converting array to object before passing into the function .kindly check the line `$item  = (object)$itemArray ;`  @GergelyLukacsy

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried (string)$item->ItemID? If I'm not mistaken, associative array keys have to be strings. Otherwise, you're using the array index, not the key.